# How incoming data is distributed among tabs in a browser?

Tags: networking

Does number of available ports limit the number of tabs that can be opened in a browser, if not the how browser knows which incoming data belongs to which tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't need to be a direct association between browser tabs and network connections.  When a tab needs to send a request to a server, it *could* open a network connection, send the request, receive the reply and then close the connection.

There are other options too:

- The browser could open multiple connections so that it can make multiple requests to the same server simultaneously.
- The browser keep old connections open so that it can sens a sequence of requests.

To get a better understanding of how a browser could interact with a webserver, refer to the HTTP specification; e.g. [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)